# Saving worksheets based on their names

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

This macro almost does exactly what I need, but I would like it to include "_sspl.xlsx" at the end of each sheet name and put the files in a folder that's named the same as the original file path.

I can't seem to get it right.

```
Sub CreateNewFolder()
Dim wbThis As Workbook
Dim wbNew As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strFilename As String

    Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook.Name
    For Each ws In wbThis.Worksheets
        strFilename = wbThis.Path & "/" & ws.Name
        ws.Copy
        Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
        wbNew.SaveAs strFilename
        wbNew.Close
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

"I can't seem to get it right" is not the most precise description of a problem :)

The following code is untested (I don't have Excel on this machine) but I *think* it will do what you want.

```
Sub CreateNewFolder()
Dim wbThis As Workbook
Dim wbNew As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet 
Dim strFilename As String

Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook
For Each ws In wbThis.Worksheets
    strFilename = wbThis.Path & "/" & ws.Name & "_sspl.xlsx"
    ws.Copy
    Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
    wbNew.SaveAs Filename:=strFilename
    wbNew.Close
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: It made sense to me lol Sorry.

Comment: I need the macro to separate out all the worksheets in the workbook and save them as their page name plus "_sspl.xlsx and into a folder named the same as the spreadsheet. If that makes sense. The code I wrote does all of that but does not include the suffix that I need and does not put them in a folder. The one you created tells me there's a 'Type mismatch' when I try to run it. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: See the edit in my code, I changed `wbThis = ThisWorkbook.Name` to `wbThis = ThisWorkbook` as `wbThis` is Dimmed as a workbook and not a string (you should be getting the same type mismatch error in your code BTW), I have since tested my code and it works

Comment: It did everything I needed but go into its own folder but I can create one, drag and drop. Thank you so much. Truly appreciative.